# On data.se.com, favorite icon does not appear if query has no description. Why?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I was browsing today some queries on [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/), and I noticed that on the list some did not present the favorite icon/count.

The icon is present in the detail. It happens only on queries that do not have a description (just the query code). See screenshot for example.
[image]
Is this a bug, or intentional behavior? If so, what is the reason?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe no one has those queries as favorite.

Comment: Nope. The vanity search in the screenshot has 1 favorite, for example.

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but the data might be cached...

Answer (score 1):

My only explanation for this at the moment is that the denormalized vote counts are out of sync with the actual votes table, since the list view uses one while the individual query view uses the other.

There may have been a glitch in the data model migration process that caused the numbers to get out of whack, but if worse comes to worst they should be able to be regenerated from the raw data in the votes table.

I'll look into it more later to see if I can find the root cause.