# Favorite stars are now small upvote triangles on SEDE

Tags: bug, design, data-explorer

The favorite icon on SEDE [used to look like a star](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119207/157841). Now it's a small upvote triangle:

[image: triangles]

Relevant [CSS](https://data.stackexchange.com/assets/css/master?v=cRohuTFUBZKhuAkRuo8K4Lx9kV_NbLGkXLFjewVInbs1) rules I'm seeing on my browser:

```
.star-off,.star-on {
    background-position: 0 -150px;
    height: 31px;
    width: 33px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    background-image: url("http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=272483674ecb");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

Mac OS X / Latest Google Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cheese-moving ba…err, okay, [quick-fixed](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/53), pending a pull and redeploy.

The stylesheets *really* need to be cleaned up anyway, so I'll make a note figure out how to deal with that sometime in the near-ish future. In the meantime I just copied the old image (which was still being served to me with that query string, though apparently not to you) locally and fixed any sstatic.net references which would be prone to this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, I totally forgot data.se is on GitHub.